# Using environment variables in Ghost v1 config

Tags: environment-variables, ghost-blog, ghost, c9.io

In Ghost 0.x, config was provided via a single config.js file with keys for each env.
In Ghost 1.0, config is provided via multiple config.json files

How do you provide environment variables in Ghost 1.0?

I would like to dynamically set the port value using process.env.port on [Cloud9 IDE](http://c9.io) like so.

**config.development.json**

```
{
  "url": "http://localhost",
  "server": {
    "port": process.env.port,
    "host": process.env.IP
  }
}
```

When I run the application using `ghost start` with the following config, it says **You can access your publication at http://localhost:2368**, but when I go to http://localhost:2368 in http://c9.io it gives me an error saying **No application seems to be running here!**

```
{
  "url": "http://localhost:2368",
  "server": {
    "port": 2368,
    "host": "127.0.0.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to figure out how to do this.

Here is the solution incase if someone else is also trying to figure out how to do the same thing.

In your **config.development.json** file, add the following.

```
{
  "url": "http://{workspace_name}-{username}.c9users.io:8080",
  "server": {
    "port": 8080,
    "host": "0.0.0.0"
  }
}
```

Alternatively, run the following command in the terminal. This will dynamically get the value for the port and host environment variable and add the above content to the **config.development.json** file.

```
ghost config url http://$C9_HOSTNAME:$PORT
ghost config server.port $PORT
ghost config server.host $IP
```